# How can I make a "browse for file.." button in VB.net?

Tags: vb.net

I'm trying to build a simple FTP uploader. How can I make it so the user can select a file to upload? See, what I want is to have a button (which I do) that a user can click, and it shows the OpenFileDialog (which I have), but then when they select a file, I want its path to be shown in a text box. How can I do that?

Answer (score 4):

Try the following code

```
Dim dialog As New OpenFileDialog()
If DialogResult.OK = dialog.ShowDialog Then
  TextBox1.Text = dialog.FileName
End If
```

Comment: Argh. Reverse order of comparison in the `If`? **In VB**?!

Comment: @Konrad, it's an almost unbreakable habit from my C days.

Comment: I’m lucky then that I made the transition in the other direction. ;-) I just hope there aren’t *too* may BASIC idioms in my C++ code.

Answer (score 1):

One way is to convert the filename to a FileInfo which contains all sorts of information about the file including the path. This opens the dialog and displays the path of the selected file.

```
If OpenFileDialog1.ShowDialog() = System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK Then
    Dim fi As New System.IO.FileInfo(OpenFileDialog1.FileName)
    TextBox1.Text = fi.DirectoryName
End If
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to get the OpenFileDialog's property Filename property. See [OpenFileDialog](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.openfiledialog_members.aspx)'s class members here on MSDN.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Add a OpenFileDialog And Add This Code

```
If YourOpenFileDialogName.ShowDialog = YourOpenFileDialogName.OK Then 
 textBox1.Text = YourOpenFileDialogName.FileName
End If
```